# A fundamental lemma of Lebesgue measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Delta_1$ be the set {[a, b]; $a \leq b, a, b \in \mathbb{R}$}.

Let $\Delta_2$ be the set {[a, b); $a \leq b, a, b \in \mathbb{R}$}.

Let $\Delta_3$ be the set {(a, b]; $a \leq b, a, b \in \mathbb{R}$}.

Let $\Delta_4$ be the set {(a, b); $a \leq b, a, b \in \mathbb{R}$}.

Let $\Delta = \Delta_1 \cup \Delta_2 \cup \Delta_3 \cup \Delta_4$.

Let $I \in \Delta$.
If $I$ is one of the forms [a, b], [a, b), (a, b], (a, b),
We define $\mu(I)$ = b - a.

Let $\Delta^n$ be the set {$I_1 \times ... \times I_n: I_1, ..., I_n \in \Delta$}.

The following proposition is trivial if we assume the theory of Lebesgue measure.
However, I think it'd be nice if we could prove it by an elementary method.

**Proposition**
There exists a unique function $\mu^n: \Delta^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies the following properties.

(1) $\mu^n(I_1 \times ... \times I_n) = \mu(I_1) \times ... \times \mu(I_n)$ for $I_1, ..., I_n \in \Delta$.

(2) Let $A, A_1、．．．、A_m \in \Delta^n$.
Suppose $A$ is a disjoint union of $A_1、．．．、A_m$.
Then $\mu^n(A) = \mu^n(A_1) + ... + \mu^n(A_m)$

**EDIT**
The above proposition can be generalized using the following notion. 
Let $X$ be a set.
Let $\Gamma$ be a subset of the power set $P(X)$.
We call $\Gamma$ a semiring on $X$.

(1) $\emptyset \in \Gamma$.

(2) If $A, B \in \Gamma$, then $A \cap B \in \Gamma$.

(3) If $A, B \in \Gamma$, then $A - B$ is a disjoint union of finitely many elements of $\Gamma$.

The above $\Delta$ is a semiring on $\mathbb{R}$.

**EDIT**
By [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161902/finitely-additive-function-on-a-product-of-semirings-of-sets), it suffices to prove the case n = 1 which is almost trivial.

**EDIT**
I came up with this problem as an application of the notion of semiring and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161902/finitely-additive-function-on-a-product-of-semirings-of-sets). I found the notion useful.

**EDIT**
A nice little feature of this proposition as a fundamental lemma of Lebesgue measure theory is that it is symmetric, i.e. you don't have to use only intervals of type [a, b)(or (a, b]).

**EDIT**
Since some people seem to think this might be my homework or a textbook exercise, let me write my opinion for posting homework/exercise as a question.
Firstly I'm not a student so that I don't have, nor will have any homework.
Nor this is a textbook exercise(I came up with it myself).
Secondly when I answer a question, I don't care whether it is homework/exercise or not.
I also don't care whether the questioner shows effort or not.
If I think it's uninteresting or too difficult, I won't answer.
Otherwise, and if I can solve it, I'll post an answer.
Usually I try to write a full proof.
If the questioner thinks that reading a full proof is not good for himself, he can always skip a part of it. In short, I solve a problem as a problem. I think this strategy makes things simpler and works well most of the time, though it might not be very pedagogical.

**EDIT**
Generally speaking, IMO, a mathematical problem should be valued only by its inherent value(not that I'm implying my question is of great value, though).
What matters is whether it is interesting and/or useful or not.
Whether it is homework/exercise or not, and whether the questioner pays enough effort to solve it or not, do not matter, or are of secondary importance.
Interesting and/or useful problems are posted and people post the answers.
This is the best part of this forum, IMO.

**EDIT**
Anyway, I wrote what I had done so far as GEdgar suggested.

**EDIT**
May I ask the reason for the downvote so that I could improve my question?
I think the question is clear. I wrote what I had done so far. I also wrote my motivation. I appreciate if you'd kindly inform me what's wrong with my question.

Comment: How is $\mu^n$ defined for something which is not a product of intervals?

Comment: I editted my question.

Comment: I editted again. Thanks.

Comment: Well, equation (1) **defines** $\mu^n$ on the set $\Delta^n$. So much for existence and uniqueness. The proof of (2) is easy but boring: partition $A$ by all hyperplanes $x_i=a_i$ and $x_i=b_i$, write $\mu^n(A)$ as product of sums, multiply out, collect the terms into $\mu^n(A_i)$

Comment: @DavideGiraudo On second thought, we don't need your equation to prove (1). So I think you misunderstood something.

Comment: characterizing finite partitions of a set in $\Delta^n$ (as in (2)),

Comment: This problem is in the text of Kolmogorov & Fomin.  (Whether from the original, or one of the problems added by Silverman for the English translation, I don't know.)  The solution is as suggested by Leonid.

Comment: @LeonidKovalev (2) can be proved elegantly if you generalize it as a problem of finitely additive functions on semirings on sets, [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161902/finitely-additive-function-on-a-product-of-semirings-of-sets]

Comment: @GEdgar Please see my comment to Leonid.